# Unable to get varnish to start

Tags: centos, nginx, wordpress, varnish

I cannot get nginx to start after changing my config file I'm very grateful for any assistance you can provide thank you :)

```
#This is a basic VCL configuration file for varnish.  See the vcl(7)
# man page for details on VCL syntax and semantics.
# 
# Default backend definition.  Set this to point to your content
# server.
# 
backend default {
  .host = "127.0.0.1";
  .port = "8080";
}
# Drop any cookies sent to Wordpress.
sub vcl_recv {
        if (!(req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)")) {
                unset req.http.cookie;
        }
}

# Drop any cookies Wordpress tries to send back to the client.
sub vcl_fetch {
        if (!(req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)")) {
               unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
        }
}
if (req.url ~ "^/(cart|my-account|checkout|addons)") {
 return (pass);
 }
if ( req.url ~ "?add-to-cart=" ) {
 return (pass);
 }
# 
# Below is a commented-out copy of the default VCL logic.  If you
# redefine any of these subroutines, the built-in logic will be
# appended to your code.
# sub vcl_recv {
#     if (req.restarts == 0) {
#   if (req.http.x-forwarded-for) {
#       set req.http.X-Forwarded-For =
#       req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
#   } else {
#       set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
#   }
#     }
#     if (req.request != "GET" &&
#       req.request != "HEAD" &&
#       req.request != "PUT" &&
#       req.request != "POST" &&
#       req.request != "TRACE" &&
#       req.request != "OPTIONS" &&
#       req.request != "DELETE") {
#         /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
#         return (pipe);
#     }
#     if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
#         /* We only deal with GET and HEAD by default */
#         return (pass);
#     }
#     if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie) {
#         /* Not cacheable by default */
#         return (pass);
#     }
#     return (lookup);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_pipe {
#     # Note that only the first request to the backend will have
#     # X-Forwarded-For set.  If you use X-Forwarded-For and want to
#     # have it set for all requests, make sure to have:
#     # set bereq.http.connection = "close";
#     # here.  It is not set by default as it might break some broken web
#     # applications, like IIS with NTLM authentication.
#     return (pipe);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_pass {
#     return (pass);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_hash {
#     hash_data(req.url);
#     if (req.http.host) {
#         hash_data(req.http.host);
#     } else {
#         hash_data(server.ip);
#     }
#     return (hash);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_hit {
#     return (deliver);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_miss {
#     return (fetch);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_fetch {
#     if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
#         beresp.http.Set-Cookie ||
#         beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
#       /*
#        * Mark as "Hit-For-Pass" for the next 2 minutes
#        */
#       set beresp.ttl = 120 s;
#       return (hit_for_pass);
#     }
#     return (deliver);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_deliver {
#     return (deliver);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_error {
#     set obj.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
#     set obj.http.Retry-After = "5";
#     synthetic {"
# <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
# <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
#  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
# <html>
#   <head>
#     <title>"} + obj.status + " " + obj.response + {"</title>
#   </head>
#   <body>
#     <h1>Error "} + obj.status + " " + obj.response + {"</h1>
#     <p>"} + obj.response + {"</p>
#     <h3>Guru Meditation:</h3>
#     <p>XID: "} + req.xid + {"</p>
#     <hr>
#     <p>Varnish cache server</p>
#   </body>
# </html>
# "};
#     return (deliver);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_init {
#   return (ok);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_fini {
#   return (ok);
# }
```

Answer (score 3):

Syntax error detected :)

Move next statements inside of sub vcl_recv:

```
if (req.url ~ "^/(cart|my-account|checkout|addons)") {
 return (pass);
 }
if ( req.url ~ "?add-to-cart=" ) {
 return (pass);
 }
```

Also, you always may check syntax of your configuration file by executing

```
varnishd -C -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl
```

(or other vcl file you have)